# Plotting 3D Surface Chart

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to plot a 3D surface. I thought it would be a pretty simple process as I have all my data in a nice table but can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

my_data2 (read in from Excel):

```
               X1      X1.1     X1.21     X1.33     X1.46     X1.61     X1.77     X1.98     X2.14     X2.35
 4e+05   291208737 291296846 291744988 292676157 304539662 347763047 346637087 352381080 361467196 334153676
 5e+05   301234194 301322304 342042259 344633543 346394275 347763047 392216772 376048898 361467196 334153676
```

The first column is my row headers.

I've tried a few different R packages but am obviously missing something.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
> r <- 1:nrow(my_data2)
> c <- 1:ncol(my_data2)
> z <- c(my_data2)
> contour3D(x=r, y=c, z=z, colvar=Volcano)
```

Error message displayed: "exactly one of the values 'x' 'y', or 'z' should be a matrix or one value"

I thought my z variable was a matrix!

Can anyone please help?
Tks

Comment: `c(my_data2)` has made `my_data` into a vector I suspect. Drop the `c()` wrapping.

Comment: I replaced the assignment for z with:
    z <- my_data2

However, this still produces the same error unfortunately.

Comment: then maybe try as.matrix(my_data2) instead of c(). that should transform your data.frame into a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the help page: "contour3D adds a contour in a 3-D plot." So I think you actually want something else. Maybe something like this:

```
library(plot3D)
z <- as.matrix(my_data2)
hist3D(z=z)
```

Comment: Thank you Vanao. That got me a working visual. I thought that because it looked like a matrix, it already was a matrix!

Comment: I also then plotted this as a 3D surface with:

    x <- 1:nrow(z)
    y <- 1:ncol(z)
    persp3D(x, y, z)